# Un équivalent français du mot romand « bugne »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

En Suisse romande, le mot [bugne](http://henrysuter.ch/glossaires/patoisB0.html#bugne) est très courant pour définir un dégât en creux, généralement d'importance mineure et causée par une compression, généralement un choc.

Bugne est donc un antonyme de "petite bosse" et employé uniquement dans le sens d'un dégât.

Typiquement on parle de bugne lorsqu'il y a un dégât à une tôle.

Exemples:

- La carosserie a quelques bugnes.
- Ma voiture est légèrement bugnée.
- Hormis quelques bugnes sans importance, l'appareil est en parfait état de fonctionnement.

Populairement, on dira aussi:
 "Tu veux une bugne ?" qui prend le sens de "Veux-tu mon poing sur la figure ?"

"Beigne" serait l'équivalent français, dans le sens de "giffle".
Est-il également employé pour qualifier des dégâts en creux ?

Sinon, quel est l'équivalent français de "bugne" dans le sens de dégât ?

Answer (score 5):

Mon coin réservant plutôt la *bugne* pour désigner une délicieuse spécialité lyonnaise, disait plutôt la *beugne* et son verbe *beugner*.

Mais ce sont des régionalismes.

En français, la bosse pouvant très bien être en creux, on utilisera simplement ce mot sachant que les professionnels de la tôle lui préfèreraient *[cabossage](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cabossage)* qui désigne autant l'action que le résultat de l'action.

Après, il existe de nombreuses solutions plus ou moins populaires, si ce n'est argotiques, à l'école on connaissait le *pain*.

Le plus répandu et reconnu par les dictionnaires pour désigner le coup et le dégat qui en résulte est sans conteste :

- Le *[gnon](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gnon)*

Comment: Merci. Effectivement, le terme de gnon semble le plus universel. Je n'y avais plus pensé. La région lyonnaise et la Romandie possèdent de nombreuses similitudes linguistiques (francoprovençal: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoproven%C3%A7al) et gastronomiques (p. ex. les cardons).

Comment: Une bosse n’est pas un creux ; voir les définitions des dictionnaires, qui ne parlent que de “protubérance”, d’“enflure”, de “saillie”, d’“élévation”, d’“éminence”, de “grosseur”.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais un *pet* /pɛt/ pour la carrosserie légèrement enfoncée que tu décris.  De là l'expression *il a un pet au casque* pour dire *il est pas très net*.

Comment: Merci pour cet éclairage. Je n'ai jamais entendu ce terme autrement que pour désigner le résultat d'une flatulence. Probablement s'agit-il d'un régionalisme ou d'un terme de jargon. Je ne pensais pas spécifiquement à une carosserie, mais il s'agissait simplement d'un exemple s'y prêtant bien.

Comment: @OuzoPower. Ça s'applique généralement à tout ce qui peut s'abimer légèrement du fait d'un petit choc, carrosserie, meuble, livre…

Comment: @OuzoPower Attention ce n’est pas la même prononciation que pour le « pet » signifiant flatulence. On prononce le t ici.

Answer (score 2):

Pour le coup dans une carrosserie, il existe le nom *poque*. D'expérience, je sais qu'il est courant au Québec, mais il peut également être entendu ou lu quelquefois en France ou en Belgique.

Cf. sens 2 [ici](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/poque).

Pour les amateurs de régionalismes, à Bruxelles on utilise également familièrement le terme de *blouch(e)* (masc. ou fém.) - cité [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_de_Belgique).

Comment: @Fólkvangr.    C'est où, ta région ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr     Réponse de Normand ?

Answer (score 1):

En français la bugne est seulement une pâtisserie;

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bugne)) ART CULIN. Spécialité lyonnaise consistant en une sorte de beignet de pâte roulée, frit dans l'huile.

En argot et français populaire c'est aussi un coup dans la figure avec la tête ou avec le poing ; le terme n'est pas enregistré au TLFi cependant, ce qui indiquerait que ce n'est pas très répandu ; je ne l'ai jamais entendu ni lu dans ce sens, mais toujours pour nommer une pâtisserie.

> [encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugne) Dans le Larousse de l'argot et français populaire, le mot bugne désigne au sens figuré : « une mandale, un coup de boule dans la tronche, un coup droit dans les artiches ».

« Beigne » ne décrirait pas ce type de détérioration parce que une beigne est une bosse ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/beigne)).
Non, « beigne » n'est pas utilisé en français pour qualifier des dégâts comme étant du type en creux. Néanmoins et de façon sujette à controverse,  pour ces dégâts on se sert de l'adjectif « [cabossé](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caboss%C3%A9) » très souvent et au lieu de dire « La carrosserie a des bugnes/beignes. » on dit « La carrosserie est cabossée. ».

Il n'y aurait pas de mot en français pour ces enfoncements (terme général en français) dont vous parlez, ces enfoncements que dans le cas spécifique des carrosseries on appelle « dents » en anglais.